# __getattribute__ in python classic class

Tags: python, attributes

As we know that, in python, new style class (class which extends object) have a predefined method `__getattribute__` to catch every attribute regardless whether it exists or not. And I'm wondering whether there is a similar function in the classic class (class which doesn't extends object)? Because `__getattribute__` is useless in classic class, and `__getattr__` is only used for the attributes that don't exist.